# I want \newcommand to replace something in a document by something else

Tags: macros

I want to define `\newcommand{\B}` in 2 different ways and switch between them in the simplest way – just using a comment mark, `%`. Let's look at the example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% My 1st definition 
\newcommand{\B}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
% My 2nd definition (it’s wrong that’s way I’m asing)
\newcommand{\B}{$\ldots$}

\begin{document}
Let \B{1.345} be 

\end{document}
```

Using first definition the value `1.345` is bolded. If I use second definition I should always get  only `$\ldots$` so value `1.345` should be removed. I tried to add spaces (crude solution) but value skipped line below. Any suggestion?

Comment: Note that the `article` class doesn't support the `9pt` fontsize option without loading, e.g, the `extsizes` package.

Comment: If you use `\renewcommand` for the second definition, you only have to add/remove *one* comment mark instead of adding one and removing one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to “gobble” the argument `{1.345}` in the `\ldots` case. (Specify `\B` with one argument but do not use `#1`.)

#### Reference for “gobbling”

- [Why does \@gobble take one argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85796/16595)

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% My 1st definition 
% \newcommand{\B}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
% My 2nd definition
\newcommand{\B}[1]{$\ldots$}% (do’nt use #1 here but specify [1])

\begin{document}
Let \B{1.345} be 

\end{document}
```

### Output

> Let … be

Comment: but how, with this approach, will it ever be possible to get the output "1.345", which is apparently wanted *sometimes*?  wouldn't an optional argument, with default of `\ldots`, be more appropriate?

Comment: @barbarabeeton If I understand Op correctly, he wants a document-wide switch so he he swaps the definition of `\B` in the preamble. One could also introduce a starred version that forces one of both settings.

Comment: You understood correctly and using a conditional (if statement) would be more elegant. But it works fine for me. Thank you. My primary purpose I described in a post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107245/automatically-enumerate-for-two-columns-and-longtable